# idx = int(float(img_id)) ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Tags: python, string, floating-point, type-conversion, valueerror

I am getting this error when I try to read my files from a given directory. My code is:

```
    box_dir = '/home/test/'
    img_id = img_metas[0]['filename'][34:40]
    idx = int(float(img_id))
    box_2d_file = box_dir + 'bbox_{:06d}.txt'.format(idx)
    with open(box_2d_file) as f:
        arrays = [list(map(float, line.split(' '))) for line in f]
    box = np.asarray(arrays)
```

I have files with filename: bbox_003200.txt, bbox_003201.txt ---- bbox_003210.txt and the content inside each file is something like this:

```
   705.95 117.81 1242.00 252.43 5.02
   1036.12 183.52 1242.00 375.00 1.96
   124.11 143.43 296.91 230.32 10.70
```

I think this is due to the empty space character between each number, or may be I am wrong, Can anyone explain a little bit about this, and how I can solve this? Thank you.

Comment: The error isn't happening when you're reading the lines. It's happening when you try to convert the number in the filename to a float.

Comment: Don't you see `img_id` in the error message?

Comment: The error message should show what the incorrect value is. Maybe you got the indexes of the slice wrong.

Comment: Why do you need `float()` when getting the number from the filename? It's just an integer.

Comment: yes now I understand, when I use: idx = int(img_id) I get this error:  idx = int(img_id)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '

Comment: Is there something unclear in that error message? The value of `img_id` is a single space, not a number.

Comment: I can't see img_id in the error message

Comment: Where it says `: ' '` the value inside the quotes is what you tried to convert to an integer.

Comment: And that's a string with just a single space.

Comment: ok, so I was trying to basically convert a space to an integer ( or float previously) which can't be done. So, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you post the value of `img_metas[0]['filename']`?

Comment: I printed out the value of img_metas[0]['filename'] with print("Image ID",img_id). It prints out : Image ID   and there is nothing, there is not value for img_id

Comment: It's probably a long string of spaces, otherwise `[34:40]` would just return an empty string, not a string with 1 space in it.

Comment: You need to examine how you're setting `img_metas` to figure out why it's setting the filename empty.